# How to declare an array with an arbitrary size

Tags: c, arrays, size, malloc

Ok, this is a C programming homework question. But I'm truly stuck.

I ask the user to input words, and then I insert the input into an array, but I can't have any control over the number of words the user types.

I guess what I'm asking is how do you declare a an array in C without declaring its length and without asking the user what the length should be.

I know this has something to do with malloc, but if you could give me some examples of how to do this, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: how about these char a[]="somename" ; ? instad of malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can realloc it every time like:

```
int size = 0;
char **array = malloc(0);
while(/* something */)
{
    char *string = // get input
    size++;
    array = realloc(array, size * sizeof(char*));
    array[size - 1] = string;
}
```

Or in chunks if you care about speed.

Comment: @Marlon Brando: just read the input into `string` and break if the user signal the input ended. if you hate c, why don't use c++?

Comment: It's a waste of time calling `malloc(0)` - the behaviour is implementation defined in that it will either allocate a block that you can't use or it will give you NULL (see C99 7.20.3). You're better off just setting it to NULL anyway which is usable by `realloc` and saves a function call.

Comment: @MarlonBrando: If you hate C then you hate programming.  Reconsider your academic plans.

Comment: @paxdiablo - An unusable block given by `malloc(0)` is still usable in `realloc`, but I agree that `malloc(0)` is pretty dumb. Also it should use `size_t size` instead of `int`.

Comment: @Carey: it's like saying "if you hate beetle car you hate cars" - programming has many sides.

Comment: No, it's not.  C is a low-level language.  It's the essence of programming made relatively simple (you haven't had a course requiring assembly, I take it).  If you hate C (without having had a lot of experience with other languages) then you simply hate programming.

Comment: @Carey: how do you know what experience he has? My CS classes went C# - assembly - C++ and everyone hated assembly but loved C# there.

Comment: @Marlo: Mainly its for performance. but recently with c++11, C has no lead over c++ so if you want performance you should go c++ these days. If you want managed language with high performance its ObjC or C#. don't have a clue what java is good for.

Comment: Java is just easier to learn. It has no regard for efficiency because it's so high-level, and on top of that, you run its code in a wasteful JVM. I learned Java first, but I'm now onto C, which they should have just taught us first.

Comment: @MarlonBrando Java's "expandable arrays" are easy to declare because you're using a Java library, ArrayList. I'm pretty sure there are C libraries for this, but it wastes time anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You can `malloc` a block of memory large enough to hold a certain number of array items.

Then, before you exceed that number, you can use `realloc` to make the memory block bigger.

Here's a bit of C code that shows this in action, reallocating an integer array whenever it's too small to hold the next integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
    int *xyzzy = NULL;   // Initially NULL so first realloc is a malloc.
    int currsz = 0;      // Current capacity.
    int i;

    // Add ten integers.

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // If this one will exceed capacity.

        if (i >= currsz) {
            // Increase capacity by four and re-allocate.

            currsz += 4;
            xyzzy = realloc (xyzzy, sizeof(int) * currsz);
                // Should really check for failure here.
        }

        // Store number.

        xyzzy[i] = 100 + i;
    }

    // Output capacity and values.

    printf ("CurrSz = %d, values =", currsz);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf (" %d", xyzzy[i]);
    }
    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I go about that?

Comment: To get better speed start with `currsz = 4` and then double `currsz` every reallocation, it will give you amortized constant time instead of linear.

Comment: Err, @Dani, surely that would be O(log N) time, yes? Not that it matters in the context of the answer, which was just showing how to use `realloc` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: well, as you were going for chunking I showed a further optimization. and its `O(1)` not `O(log n)`

Comment: Everyone says that doubling it each time is the best, but I don't really understand why. Just adding the capacity for one more element each time must be bad, but is there a middle ground?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want malloc. Checkout this tut.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/dynamic_memory_allocation.html

This site is good in general for learning.

Here is an example of using realloc, it is basically exactly what you are asking to do.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/

Comment: but he doesn't know the size even on run time.

Comment: malloc is still appropriate, and as @pax pointed out you simply realloc.

Answer (score -1):

0) obviously you will need multiple buffers, so you will need a list like structure: perhaps a record with char array 100 chars and a pointer to next structure
1) You need to capture the words char by char and store them in your buffer
2) once the buffer is full you allocate another record, chain it with the previous one and keep going until you are out of mem or the process is over.

That should be better performance than realloc function. I believe malloc is trying to give contious block of memory. Therefore the list like structure will be faster and work better.

Comment: And what if the user types in a word with more than 100 chars?  And why waste 95 characters on most of the words most users will enter?  There's a lot more performance in realloc() than you realize.

Comment: Malloc may seem to give a continuous block of memory, but because of VM it isn't continues and can be fragmented. That mean realloc might not even call copy.

Comment: @gregory 100 bytes is just an example. The c vesion of realloc has no smarts. If you are talking about some fancy implementation please say which one you have in mind.

Comment: @dani I am talking about normal c malloc. It works only with continious block of memory. Novadays most OSes are smarter then that and provide more dynamic behaviour. However this guy is in school and i am sure that his teacher wants to teach/show them the basic memory structures like linked list etc . . Not fancy alloc/realloc functions . .