# Using Array for Unknown number of inputs in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Say, I want to get several Integer Inputs from the User.

It may be 10, 100 , 1000 (or) 10000 inputs that entirely depends upon the user.

I want to store them in the Array and refer to any i-th input as necessary.

Is it Possible using Array?

Comment: What signals the end of input? I mean, there is no way for the computer to know that the input has ended.

Comment: Of course it's possible. Just create an array of 10000 elements. That meets the requirements as specified in your question. But I assume you are actually trying to ask something else. If so, please clarify your question to more clearly describe your inputs (e.g. how the user indicates no more input) and any other constraints of your problem.

Comment: Okay, a bit more clearer.
Say, I shall give the number of inputs at beginning.
And then,
I want to declare the array of that specified 'no. of inputs' ?
Because, I want to go to any i-th element, I think Array is the choice!
I didn't hope it is possible with pointers?

Comment: The general approach is to allocate some reasonable anticipated number of integers (initializing all to zero by allocation with `calloc` has advantage here), keep a count of the inputs and when the inputs reach the number allocated, then `realloc` the array `2x` the original. There are many ways to handle this situation, but variations of this is pretty standard. There are hundreds of example already on this site.

Comment: what is the highest possible number of bytes that I can get by this dynamic allocation ?

Comment: It depends on the memory size of Your machine.

Comment: How can I reach any i-th element with this pointer ?

Comment: @SathyamoorthyR Please learn the basics of C, i.e, arrays and how to access them. Then, learn about pointers. Then google and find out what dynamic memory allocation is and what has `malloc` got to do with it. I've said this because you seem to lack basic C programming skills.

Comment: @Cool Guy , Yup! I know the basics!
Sometimes, When I declare an array of size A[4000][4000] , I end up with Segmentation fault ?

Comment: If so, google it; Something like "_declaring large arrays segmentation fault c_" and you'll find loads of results solving that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int readNum()
{
    int c;
    int buffer = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' && c >= '0' && c <= '9')
    {
        buffer = (buffer * 10) + (c - '0');
    }
    return buffer;
}

int *readNumsToArray()
{
    size_t maxSize = 64;
    size_t i = 0;
    int *intArr = malloc(sizeof(*intArr) * maxSize);
    int buffer;
    while ((buffer = readNum()) != 0)
    {
        intArr[i++] = buffer;
        if (i == maxSize)
        {
            maxSize *= 2;
            intArr = realloc(intArr, sizeof *intArr * maxSize);
            if (intArr == NULL) break;
        }
    }
    if (buffer == 0)
        intArr[i] = buffer;
    return intArr;
}

int main()
{
    int *nums = readNumsToArray();
    size_t i = 0;
    while(nums[i] != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", nums[i++]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This program accepts numbers till a 0.
The individual numbers are read till a '\n' char.
If you want the i-th element you can just type nums[i].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `malloc` function.
If you wish to allocate an array dynamically, the following code can be used:

```
   int * array = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

This computes the number of bytes that ten integers occupy in memory, then requests that many bytes from malloc and assigns the result to a pointer named `array` 
When the program no longer needs the dynamic array, it should call free to return the memory it occupies to the free store:

```
free(array);
```

Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation)

[How do i declare an array of undefined or no initial size](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7871087/5206468)

[Using array for unknown number of inputs in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7871081/5206468)

Comment: What if I want get the value of 7-th element in the list ?

Comment: @SathyamoorthyR `array[6]` (6 because in C, array indexing start from 0)